Sub Panel location changed from side to the front side of the house access issue from the attic
Advice and idea's please
The location of the subpanel has been moved from the side of the house to now the front. Coming out of the attic we would have to be in the Eave straight down. There is not enough space to accommodate a 2" PVC 90 going down. There is no room to access a condulet fitting cover thought about using that.
Can I set a 12 by 12 J box in attic and come out of that with liquid tight metallic raceway to the subpanel I will more than likely have to install a little unistrut depending on where we come out. Can't come out flush due to the closeness of the eave meeting the side of the house.
Everywhere that I have looked and read and searched and even the WAC says Outdoor wiring (120/240 volts) exposed to moisture and mechanical damage must be protected by rigid metal conduit, electrical metallic tubing, liquid-tight flexible metal conduit, or nonmetallic conduit. The conductors shall be type RW, TW, or equivalent.
I have only found that reference is my thinking correct? The sub is 100 amp the breaker back at the main panel will be a 90 amp



Any wire outside must be wet rated.  Cables below 8 feet must be protected.  Single wires(not cable) must be in conduit(electric rated, not any metal/plastic pipe).  Your local permit department might have extra requirements.

I can't see a way to install that conduit without opening the roof.

Is there any reason you can't simply drop a SER cable out the soffit and down to the panel?  Generally speaking, a cable up that high isn't susceptible to the things that mess up outdoor wiring (such as weedwhackers)

Assume this is a new construction or heavy rehab house?

The area I have to work with is at the very bottom of the pitch of the roof there is about 6" of space and there is a 2x6 support for the joist that we can't move. The solution that I came up with is LMC From the 12x12 box to a 90 degree fitting down the eave into the panel. There is just enough room for me to get a small channel locks to tighten the fitting. I have searched the WAC and the NEC and haven't found any reference that I am doing it wrong. The wire is rated for the location. This is a living in it house just adding the subpanel.

The other option that I offered to her was to drop down in the corner of the room below using condilets and going out the wall there and she could have something built to cover it. She vetoed that. Put the thinking cap back on and researched. I just want to make sure that I am not doing something that is out of code.

The SER cable was vetoed by the owner.
